# how to place a variable in jquery css('width', ' ') method

Tags: jquery

I would like to use variable in css('width', 'topPosition+"px"')method but whether I try 'px' or other ways it is not working.

```
$("document").ready(function () {
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var topPosition = $('#cialo').scrollTop();
    console.log(topPosition);
    if (topPosition != 0) {
        $("logoBg").css('margin-top', 'topPosition+"px"')
    };
});
```

How to do it?

Comment: what is 'logoBg'?? is it any class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your topPosition will be string in your code,

```
$(".logoBg").css('margin-top', topPosition+"px");   
// replace .logoBg with . if class and with # if id of element
```

Replace this line in your code, it will work.

Answer (score 3):

Please try this: If logoBg is class

```
$(".logoBg").css('margin-top', topPosition+'px');
```

If logoBg is id

```
$("#logoBg").css('margin-top', topPosition+'px');
```

Comment: what is loogoBg is it class string or id ? have you noticed ?

Answer (score 2):

Replace your `$("logoBg").css('margin-top', 'topPosition+"px"')` line of code with my code below::

*Assuming you have class name called "logoBg"*

```
$(".logoBg").css('margin-top', topPosition);
```

**OR**

```
$(".logoBg").css('margin-top', topPosition+'px');
```

**PLEASE NOTE::**

If your 'logoBg' is class use it like `$('.logoBg')` **(class selector)** or if ID then use it like`$('#logoBg')` **(ID selector)**

Comment: what is loogoBg is it class string or id ? have you noticed ?

Comment: I have asked him a question have you noticed?

Comment: Consequently, your answer is wrong then even if you mentioned it in comment, right ?

Comment: @rahul_m OK. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Change marginTop and topPosition is a var, no need quotes.

```
$(".logoBg").css('marginTop', topPosition+'px')
```

Comment: what is loogoBg is it class string or id ? have you noticed ?

Answer (score 1):

The quotes are wrong in `'topPosition+"px"'`, this code should work:

```
$("document").ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var topPosition = $('#cialo').scrollTop();
        console.log(topPosition);
        if (topPosition != 0) {
            $("logoBg").css('margin-top', String(topPosition) + 'px');
        };
    });
```

`$("logoBg")` i suppose should be `$(".logoBg")` (if its a class name), because doesn't exist an html tag named logobg.

Comment: what is loogoBg is it class string or id ? have you noticed ?

Answer (score 1):

mention that "logoBg" is id or class in jquery code . there is no "#" or "."